# Virtual box on Ubuntu crashes when using Windows XP guest

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

Every time I try to use,Windows XP as a guest on virtual box it causes my Ubuntu host to crash. I've tried setting the memory in different ways (such as lowering it), but it still causes my Ubuntu to crash to the black screen and hang on "Recovering Journal". I know it hangs because the computer is running that way for more than 30 minutes...

So how would I be able to fix this? By the way, Ubuntu is running as the host by a booted flash drive.

Edit: I first started with 1024 MB out of 3584 MB of RAM for the guest. Then I tried 850 MB of RAM for the guest, which still causes the crash. I went down to 350 MB of RAM for the guest, but it just keeps crashing. Is there a way to fix this? By the way, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'm curious if there are any messages in the host OS logs?

Comment: None that I've found. I found a way to make it work finally, but that is to use the guest at 64 MB because if i go above 100 it crashes.